# TypeScript 2.8: Simplification of type safe reducers?

Tags: typescript

I was reading this article https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/improved-redux-type-safety-with-typescript-2-8-2c11a8062575 and I was inspired to simplify my reducer through the use of `ReturnType<A[keyof A]>` based on `typeof myActionFunction`.

However, it seems like something is lost in translation, because if I create my action types explicitly with something like

```
export interface MyFirstAction extends Action<MyEnum.FirstAction> {
    someProperty: string;
}
export interface MySecondAction extends Action<MyEnum.SecondAction> {
    someOtherProperty: number;
}
```

In my reducer I can do

```
export const reducer: Reducer<MyModel, Action> = (state: MyModel = initialState, action: MyFirstAction | MySecondAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case MyEnum.FirstAction: {
            const x = action.someProperty; // x is string
            return state;
        }
        case MyEnum.SecondAction {
            const y = action.someOtherProperty; // y is number
            return state;
       }
    }
...
```

If the action creators are

```
export const firstAction = (someProperty: string) => ({type: MyEnum.FirstAction, someProperty});
export const secondAction = (someOtherProperty: number) => ({type: MyEnum.SecondAction, someOtherProperty});
```

This is all type safe, and works out of the box, which unfortunately it does not if I use

```
type MyFirstAction = ReturnType<typeof firstAction>;
type MySecondAction = ReturnType<typeof secondAction>;
```

Instead of explicitly declaring my Action interfaces.

E.g. in the second case block, I would get something like `TS2339 Property 'someOtherProperty' does not exist on type ...` because the type system does not seem to be able to discriminate between them if the type is inferred using `ReturnType` instead of explicit interfaces.

Why is that, and is there something I can do about it (so that I can simplify my code, reduce boiler plate, and be just as happy)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Typescript will not infer literal types for object literal properties, so the type for `{type: MyEnum.FirstAction, someProperty}` will be `{type: MyEnum, someProperty: string }` not `{type: MyEnum.FirstAction, someProperty: string }`. The simplest solution is to use a type assertion to force the compiler to infer the literal type not the enum type:

```
type MyFirstAction = ReturnType<typeof firstAction>;
type MySecondAction = ReturnType<typeof secondAction>;

export const firstAction = (someProperty: string) => ({ type: MyEnum.FirstAction as MyEnum.FirstAction, someProperty });
export const secondAction = (someOtherProperty: number) => ({ type: MyEnum.SecondAction as MyEnum.SecondAction, someOtherProperty });

export const reducer: Reducer<MyModel, Action> = (state: MyModel = initialState, action: MyFirstAction | MySecondAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case MyEnum.FirstAction: {
            const x = action.someProperty; // x is string
            return state;
        }
        case MyEnum.SecondAction: {
            const y = action.someOtherProperty; // y is number
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```